# Python: extract column from pandas pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, aggregate

I have a pivoted table
`total_chart = df.pivot_table(index="Name", values="Items", aggfunc='count')`
The output gives

```
A              8
B             52
C             24
D              6
E             43
F              5
G             13
I              1
```

I trying to get only the second column (number only)
Is there any simple way to get it?

Comment: `df['Names'].value_counts().to_list()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should do the trick for you.
It counts "Items", sort it ascending by the index "Name" and output just the counts without the index.

```py
df['Items'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True).tolist()
```

Comment: Many thanks, Scott and Robni.
Can data output  be sorted by "Name" (not by "Items")

Comment: Of course. Just replace "Items" with "Name".

Comment: actually, I still need numbers in the list in the  sequence [8, 52, 24, 6, 43, 5, 13,1]
Sorted by "names' not by "items"
The current output is   [52, 43, 24, 13, 8, 6, 5, 1]

Comment: df['Items'].value_counts(sort=True).sort_index(ascending=True).tolist() should do the trick for you.